# error: unresolved reference: mongodb in Kotlin

Tags: mongodb, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin. I want to perform basic CRUD operations with Mongo DB and I get the following error:

`error: unresolved reference: mongodb`

for this line of code:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
```

I have added the following dependency in the build of the module in Android Studio (Intellij IDE).

`implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:3.11.0'`

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
This is the project hierarchy. I work with DBOps.kts

[image: Project hierarchy]

Comment: In general the artifact ID aka `org.mongodb`, should match the package, aka, `com.mongodb`. Have you tried `import org.mongodb.BasicDBObject`? Are you using an IDE? Does your IDE have anything to say about this import?

Comment: @PiRocks I use Android Studio. How can I make sure they match? The import code is the first line of my code. The IDE does not provide any more info. Just unresolved reference.

Comment: Android studio should have a global search functionality triggered by hitting shift a few times in succession. Have you tried searching for BasicDBOBject via that?

Comment: I can find the class via that. It seems that the DB mongo is known to the IDE but not to the kotlin script. I need to also say that I have create another folder (in the 'src' folder) which contains the kotlin script. I do not know if the gradle build file is just for the code in the 'main' folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using legacy code.

Here is the correct one for that.

```
dependencies {
      compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.13.3'
}
```

Reference : https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/installation-guide/

---

**EDIT**

I have tried myself, and it works, so I guess there is another issue.
After importing library via Gradle, you could check it is imported correctly from `Project -> External Libraries`(Check below image)

[image]
[image]

If you cannot see the MongoDB library from there, there is a possibility that IDE has some problems. So I would recommend reset caches(`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`), clean build, and rebuild the project.

[image]

Comment: compile is deprecated. It is suggested to use implementation. Used the driver dependency as you suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: It didn't work. It seems that the DB mongo is known to the IDE but not to the kotlin script. I need to also say that I have create another folder (in the 'src' folder) which contains the kotlin script. I do not know if the gradle build file is just for the code in the 'main' folder

Comment: Yeah, usually Grade will look only `src/main` folder if you don't do anything to Gradle build scripts. Why don't you just try to put the kotlin script to the `src/main` folder?